# Test Ionic + Anguar app Platform.backButton undefined error when calling subscribeWithPriority()

Tags: angular, testing, ionic-framework

I'm setting up a basic test suit for my very small Ionic + Angular app.

In my `app.component.ts` I subscribe to the `backButton` event:

```js
this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
  // some code
});
```

and when I run `ng test` I get the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property ‘subscribeWithPriority’ of undefined

meaning that backButton is not defined in the test. So, I added backButton this way:

```js
platformSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Platform', {
  ready: platformReadySpy,
  backButton: mockBackButton,  // a mock function
});
```

but the test is still complaining that `backButton` is not a function.

Is there a way to mock `Platform` and `backButton` to solve this issues?

These are the two files related to the issue:

`app.component.ts:`

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import { Platform, IonRouterOutlet, AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { Location } from '@angular/common';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { App } = Plugins;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})

export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChild(IonRouterOutlet, {static: true}) routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private location: Location,
    private alertController: AlertController
  ) {
    this.initializeApp();
    this.backButtonEvent();
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  backButtonEvent() {
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10, () => {
      if (!this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()) {
        this.backButtonAlert();
      } else {
        this.location.back();
      }
    });
  }

  async backButtonAlert() {
    // code for showing alert...
  }
}
```

`app.component.spec.ts:`

```js
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let statusBarSpy;
  let splashScreenSpy;
  let platformReadySpy;
  let platformSpy;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    statusBarSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('StatusBar', ['styleDefault']);
    splashScreenSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SplashScreen', ['hide']);
    platformReadySpy = Promise.resolve();
    platformSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('Platform', { ready: platformReadySpy });

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: StatusBar, useValue: statusBarSpy },
        { provide: SplashScreen, useValue: splashScreenSpy },
        { provide: Platform, useValue: platformSpy },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should initialize the app', async () => {
    TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    expect(platformSpy.ready).toHaveBeenCalled();
    await platformReadySpy;
    expect(statusBarSpy.styleDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(splashScreenSpy.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  // ... more tests

});
```

Software versions:
Ionic (6.12.3) + Angular (10.0.14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem by creating my own Platform mock:

```js
class MockBackButton {
  subscribeWithPriority: jasmine.Spy<any>;
}

class MockPlatform {
  ready: jasmine.Spy<any>;
  backButton: any;
}
```

and by assigning it to the spy this way:

```js
const platformReadySpy = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());

mockBackButton = new MockBackButton();
mockBackButton.subscribeWithPriority = jasmine.createSpy('subscribeWithPriority', (priority, fn) => {});

mockPlatform = new MockPlatform();
mockPlatform.ready = platformReadySpy;
mockPlatform.backButton = mockBackButton;
```

This is the working `app.component.spec.ts`

```js
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA } from '@angular/core';
import { TestBed, async } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { App } = Plugins;

class MockBackButton {
  subscribeWithPriority: jasmine.Spy<any>;
}

class MockPlatform {
  ready: jasmine.Spy<any>;
  backButton: any;
}

describe('AppComponent', () => {

  let statusBarSpy;
  let splashScreenSpy;
  let platformReadySpy;
  let mockPlatform;
  let mockBackButton;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    statusBarSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('StatusBar', ['styleDefault']);
    splashScreenSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('SplashScreen', ['hide']);
    const platformReadySpy = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue(Promise.resolve());
    
    mockBackButton = new MockBackButton();
    mockBackButton.subscribeWithPriority = jasmine.createSpy('subscribeWithPriority', (priority, fn) => {});
    
    mockPlatform = new MockPlatform();
    mockPlatform.ready = platformReadySpy;
    mockPlatform.backButton = mockBackButton;

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent],
      schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
      providers: [
        { provide: StatusBar, useValue: statusBarSpy },
        { provide: SplashScreen, useValue: splashScreenSpy },
        { provide: Platform, useValue: mockPlatform },
      ],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should create the app', () => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should initialize the app', async () => {
    TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    expect(mockPlatform.ready).toHaveBeenCalled();
    await platformReadySpy;
    expect(statusBarSpy.styleDefault).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(splashScreenSpy.hide).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  // more tests...

});
```

Thanks to [jettmarks](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-4-angular-8-test-failure/181245/2).